# Whole curve changing from point

Tags: modeling

Curve acting silly

I've been trying to make curves with hair recently, and its all been fine until right now. I looked up a tutorial for making curls, and added *Add Curve: Extra Objects*.

After that, the curve has not been acting right. Whenever I try to scale a point or let alone move it, the whole thing has been changing.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: oh ok sorry, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

The curve is acting strange because it's a "[Nurbs curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/surfaces/structure.html)". Try using a Bezier Curve instead.

[image]

Comment: Yeah the problem is though I need a path but thanks!

Comment: That's what a Bezier curve is though, your issue is you are using a nurbs curve and you need to use a Bezier curve for what you are attempting. Use whatever shape of curve/path you want. It has to be a Bezier curve though.